# Why is WebView not adding the JavascriptInterface when in landscape orientation

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I have created a user manual for my app written in html.  It has a contents page with links to other sections.  I load the html file into WebView and all works fine.  What I want to do is when the user swaps from portrait to landscape, keep the same scroll position as they were before, and vice versa from landscape back to portrait. I created a class WebScrollListener with method onScrollPositionChange.  This is added to the WebView as a JavascriptInterface so the Javascript sets the values for the variables in the method. I've got it working fine going from portrait to landscape for the first time but once in landscape, the WebScrollListener stops listening for scroll events. Here is the code for my Fragment.

```
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

           int fragmentId = scenarioViewModel.getCurrentFragmentId();
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_manual, container, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // orientation changed has occurred
            initialScrollElement = savedInstanceState.getString("scrollElement");
            initialScrollMargin = savedInstanceState.getInt("scrollMargin");
        }

        webview = root.findViewById(R.id.help_text);

        hashTag = getHashTag(fragmentId);

        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        WebViewClient webViewClient = new MyWebViewClient();
        webview.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);

        scrollListener = new WebScrollListener();
        webview.addJavascriptInterface(scrollListener, "WebScrollListener");
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/app-user-manual.html");

        return root;
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("scrollElement", scrollListener.element);
        outState.putInt("scrollMargin", scrollListener.margin);
    }

   private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            if (initialScrollElement != null) {
                // It's very hard to detect when web page actually finished loading;
                // At the time onPageFinished is called, page might still not be parsed
                // Any javascript inside <script>...</script> tags might still not be executed;
                // Dom tree might still be incomplete;
                // So we are gonna use a combination of delays and checks to ensure
                // that scroll position is only restored after page has actually finished loading
                view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        StringBuilder buf=new StringBuilder("javascript:scrollToPosition('"+initialScrollElement+"','"+initialScrollMargin+"')");
                        Log.d("MyWebViewClient", "returned string:"+buf.toString());
                        webview.loadUrl(buf.toString());
                        initialScrollElement = null;
                    }
                }, 300);
            } else {
               if (url.contains("#") != true) {
                    // We only go into this method if the user has clicked on the help button
                    // and we want to go to a specific hashtag.  The page gets reloaded at that hashtag.
                    if (!hashTag.isEmpty()) {
                        String myurl = url + hashTag;
                        // this gets loaded again so as to get the position of the hashtag
                        webview.loadUrl(myurl);
                    }
                }
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        }
    }

 public class WebScrollListener {

        private String element;
        private int margin;

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void onScrollPositionChange(String topElementCssSelector, int topElementTopMargin) {
            Log.d("WebScrollListener", "Scroll position changed: " + topElementCssSelector + " " + topElementTopMargin);
            element = topElementCssSelector;
            margin = topElementTopMargin;
        }
    }
```

The javascript is included inside the html file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scroll-position.js"></script>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
    // We will find first visible element on the screen 
    // by probing document with the document.elementFromPoint function;
    // we need to make sure that we dont just return 
    // body element or any element that is very large;
    // best case scenario is if we get any element that 
    // doesn't contain other elements, but any small element is good enough;
    var findSmallElementOnScreen = function() {
      var SIZE_LIMIT = 1024;
      var elem = undefined;
      var offsetY = 0;
      while (!elem) {
          var e = document.elementFromPoint(100, offsetY);
          if (e.getBoundingClientRect().height < SIZE_LIMIT) {
              elem = e;
          } else {
              offsetY += 50;
          }
      }
      return elem;
  };

  // Convert dom element to css selector for later use
  var getCssSelector = function(el) {
      if (!(el instanceof Element)) 
          return;
      var path = [];
      while (el.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
          var selector = el.nodeName.toLowerCase();
          if (el.id) {
              selector += '#' + el.id;
              path.unshift(selector);
              break;
          } else {
              var sib = el, nth = 1;
              while (sib = sib.previousElementSibling) {
                  if (sib.nodeName.toLowerCase() == selector)
                     nth++;
              }
              if (nth != 1)
                  selector += ':nth-of-type('+nth+')';
          }
          path.unshift(selector);
          el = el.parentNode;
      }
      return path.join(' > ');    
  };

  // Send topmost element and its top offset to java
  var reportScrollPosition = function() {
      var elem = findSmallElementOnScreen();
      if (elem) {
          var selector = getCssSelector(elem);
          var offset = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top;
          WebScrollListener.onScrollPositionChange(selector, offset);
      }
  }

  // We will report scroll position every time when scroll position changes,
  // but timer will ensure that this doesn't happen more often than needed
  // (scroll event fires way too rapidly)
  var previousTimeout = undefined;
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
      clearTimeout(previousTimeout);
      previousTimeout = setTimeout(reportScrollPosition, 200);
  });

  function scrollToPosition (selectorToRestore, positionToRestore) {
    var previousTop = 0;
    var check = function() {
        var elem = document.querySelector(selectorToRestore);
        if (!elem) {
         setTimeout(check, 100);
          return;
        }
        var currentTop = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        if (currentTop != previousTop) {
          previousTop = currentTop;
          setTimeout(check,100);
        } else {
          window.scrollBy(0, currentTop - positionToRestore);
        }
    }
    check();
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

onCreate entry point your webview add condition for everything works fine except JavascriptInterface NEVER works after orientation change :

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
    webView = root.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    if (webView != null) {
        String URL = (savedInstanceState == null) ? "" : savedInstanceState.getString("URL");
        if (URL.equals("")) {
            webView.loadUrl("yourhome.html");    
        } else {
            webView.loadUrl(URL);   // this is saved in onSaveInstanceState 
        }
    }
    return root;
 }
```

Comment: This didn't work.  The URL saved in onSavedInstanceState is the URL that was loaded but not the scrolled to position after the page load.  So instead of going to the last position that was scrolled to, upon orientation change it goes back to the position the user was at when the page was first loaded.  The problem is in WebScrollListener interfacing with javascript.  When scrolling in portrait I can see the output from Logcat of the current scroll position.  When I go to landscape and scroll, there is no output in Logcat meaning WebScrollListener is not getting called from javascript

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the javascript function findSmallAlementOnScreen.  This function had a SIZE_LIMIT of 1024 but using the debugger I found that in landscape this was exceeded so the top element was never found.

This method now works perfectly with just two lines of code.

```
 var findSmallElementOnScreen = function() {
    var range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(0,0); // screen coordinates of upper-left corner of a scolled area (in this case screen itself)
    var element = range.startContainer.parentNode; // this an upper onscreen element
    return element;
  };
```